# MailApp+SpreadsheetApp - passing an object property as an email subject

Tags: json, object, google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

noob programer here.

I'm working on a gsheets script that should receive an answer from google forms(that submits the answer to a google sheets sheet), formats it into an email and mails it to somebody else.

I've writen the code to take the header and the form submission row into a javascript object, but I wasn't able to figure out the reason why  I cant use one of the object's properties as the subject of the email, I get the email but the subject always comes as "Mail test undefined".

note: The ifEdit method is triggered as an *Installed* Event Listener for the OnEdit event.

```
/* DEFINE GLOBAL VARIABLES */
function globalVariables(){ 
  let varArray = {
    spreadsheetId   : 's0mer4nd0mIdnumb3r',                               
    sheetID         : '0',
    sheetName       : 'sheetname'
  };
  return varArray;
}

function ifEdit(event) {
  let range = event.range;//The range of cells edited
  let columnOfCellEdited = range.getColumn();//Get column number

  let emailAddress = "generic@email.com.zb";
  let message = JSON.stringify(
    convertToObjects(
      getSheetHeaderAsArray(range.getSheet()), 
      getRowAsArray(range.getRow(), range.getSheet())
      )).toString();
  let subject = "Mail test " + message["MATERIAL"];

  if (columnOfCellEdited === 1 && range.getSheet().getName() == globalVariables().sheetName) {// Column 1 is Column A
    range.setNote('Edited at +' + new Date());
    Logger.log(emailAddress + subject + message);
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  };
}

/** AUXILIARY **/

function convertToObjects(headers, rows){
  let result = {};
  headers[0].forEach((headers, i) => result[headers] = rows[0][i]);
  console.log(result);
  return result;
}

function getSheetHeaderAsArray(sheet){
  let header = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, 14).getValues();
  //Logger.log(header);
  return header;
}

function getRowAsArray(editedRowNum, sheet){
  let rowArray = sheet.getRange(editedRowNum, 1, 1, 14).getValues();
  //Logger.log(rowArray);
  return rowArray;
}
```

Comment: Do you realize that the onedit trigger only fires for user edits?

Comment: This might have a better chance of working `message["MATERIAL"];` if you hadn't  stringified the message

Comment: It looks to me like you're trying to run an onEdit() trigger on a sheet that's linked to a form assuming that a onFormSubmit edit will trigger on onEdit trigger and I don't think it will.

Comment: I didn't actually, but fortunately changing the trigger from onEdit to onFormSubmit fixed this problem, but for some reason now it applies the .setNote to every cell in the range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this maybe close to what you were trying to accomplish:

```
function ifEdit(e) {
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  const emailAddress = "generic@email.com.zb";
  const hA=sh.getRange(1,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  const rA=sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  let mObj = {};
  hA.forEach((h,i)=>{mObj[h]=rA[i];});
  const message = hA.join(',') + '\n' + rA.join(',');
  let subject = "Mail test " + mObj["MATERIAL"];

  if (e.range.rowStart == 1 && range.getSheet().getName() == globalVariables().sheetName) {// Column 1 is Column A
    range.setNote('Edited at +' + new Date());
    Logger.log(emailAddress + subject + message);
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  };
}
```

But unfortunately I believe you're expecting the edit trigger from the onFormSubmit trigger and that's not going to happen.

Comment: Thanks! I had to rewrite it for some reason, but it works as intended! You're right about the edit trigger not activating based on the edit, so I've changed the trigger from the edit to the OnFormSubmit. now I just need to make the email body look pretty :D